# Getting the newest record from a database Multiple queries

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a mysql database with vehicles records. I need a fast query that will return the newest records of those records that were updated within the last 4 minutes. For example vehicle "A" may be updated several times a minute so it will appear many times within the last 4min. Same with vehicle B C etc. I need only the most recent entries for each vehicle within a 4 min window. I have tried like this

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable AS a
WHERE a.ts = 
(SELECT MAX(ts)
 FROM yourtable AS b
 WHERE b.ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
   AND b.name = a.name)
```

but it takes too long to produce results >10seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the self-join.

```
select max(ts), name from Table1
where ts >  NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
group by name
```

Comment: wont work. the above code is not returing the most recent updated values

Comment: Can you post an example of your data?

Comment: for example the highlighted lines should be returned http://www.syros.aegean.gr/users/dpsd05010/data.jpg  in a 20min window this example

Comment: Please post the data in text form to pastebin so I can import it to my database and test.

Comment: www.syros.aegean.gr/users/dpsd05010/dokimastikospinakas.xls

Comment: Cheked it, query and results [here](http://pastebin.com/3MiegRgT). Looks ok and fits the results in the data.jpg file.  Make sure the ts column is defined as "timestamp".

Answer (score 1):

To get all the rows for the latest updates and not only the name and timestamp:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
      TableX AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT name
             , MAX(ts) AS maxts
        FROM TableX
        WHERE ts >  NOW() - INTERVAL 4 MINUTE
        GROUP BY name
      ) AS grp
    ON  grp.name = t.name
    AND grp.maxts = t.ts
```

You'll need at least an index on the timestamp column for this query.